# How to configure database driver on gammu-smsd

Tags: mysql, sms, gammu

When I type "gammu-smsd -c smsdrc" to configure gammu-smsd I got this error

> gammu-smsd: The native_mysql driver was not compiled in!

Who can help me to solve this?

In the config file smsdrc, I have :

```
service = SQL
...
user = root
password = 
pc = localhost
database = gammu
...
driver = native_mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

The native database backends are [currently not built in the official Windows binaries](https://github.com/gammu/gammu/issues/338), help or bounties to make that happen are welcome. You can however use [ODBC driver instead](https://wammu.eu/docs/manual/smsd/odbc.html).

If you're on Linux and compiled Gammu yourself, the MySQL development files were not installed when compiling, see [Gammu manual for more information](https://wammu.eu/docs/manual/project/install.html#compiling-on-linux-unix-systems).

Comment: Thanks! And do you know why when I use files backend I don't see the received message?
I'm in windows 10